# How to get hold of Component instance

Tags: restlet

I am running a tomcat server and my web.xml is as follows. I need to get an instance of TaskService from the Component class. I am not explicitly creating a Component. I believe the ServerServlet class is internally creating an implicit Component. 
My question is how do I get access to the implicit Component instance?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServiceGateway</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.ServiceApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right! The servlet extension of Restlet creates a component under the hood for you.

There is no really direct way to get it. That said, you can browse contexts to reach its instance.

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        // Get restlet context
        Context context = getContext();

        // Get servlet context
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) attrs.get(
                  "org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServletContext");

        // Get restlet component
        Component component = (Component) servletContext.getAttribute(
         "org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.component.ServerServlet");

        (...)
    }
}
```

Here is the configuration I used within the file `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="myApplication" version="2.5">
    <display-name>My Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
            <param-value>test.RestletApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Another way is to configure the servlet with your own Component. This correspond to the mode #2 in this page http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.3/jee/ext/org/restlet/ext/servlet/ServerServlet.html

Comment: Hello, can you help with this Restlet bug? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422942/timeout-while-writing-to-the-queue-based-output-stream-google-app-engine